# Excel VBA How to combine 2+ similar macros to avoid mass modules

Tags: excel, vba

So as I'm ramping up a bit here, I'm also realizing how annoying it is to create an individual module for every single calculation I'm running via VBA.

I have a lot of macros similar to the following 2 below, is there a simple way to combine them into one module?  Also, if I combine them, will they actually run in order (i.e. runs first formula, then second, third, etc..?)

```
Sub V1()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CT Accounts")

        .Cells(4, 4).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4 ="""","""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,DCTM!B:B,1,0),VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!B4,DCTM!B:B,1,0)))"

    End With
End Sub
```

Macro number 2 .. (and honestly I have like 15-20 of these in the same workbook)

```
Sub V2()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CT Accounts")
    With .Cells(4, 5).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
        .Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4  ="""","""",VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,'Master Control'!A:R,18,0))"
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

And number 3..and on and on and on

```
Sub V3()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CT Accounts")
    With .Cells(4, 6).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
        .Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4="""","""",VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,Inactive!A:T,20,0))"
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can create an array of formulas and write them in one go (I think).

Comment: You can put multiple macros in the same module.  Just copy and paste the stuff from the one module to the other.  Then you can right-click on the empty module and choose Remove.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
    Sub CombineV123()
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CT Accounts")
    
            .Cells(4, 4).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4 ="""","""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,DCTM!B:B,1,0),VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!B4,DCTM!B:B,1,0)))"
    
           With .Cells(4, 5).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
                .Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4  ="""","""",VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,'Master Control'!A:R,18,0))"
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
           End With
               
           With .Cells(4, 6).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
                .Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4="""","""",VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,Inactive!A:T,20,0))"
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
           End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do the row counting once, then you can re-use the calculated range

```
Sub AddAllFormulas()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CT Accounts")
        Set rng = .Rows(4).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    End With
    
    With rng
        .Columns("D").Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4 ="""","""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,DCTM!B:B,1,0),VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!B4,DCTM!B:B,1,0)))"
        With .Columns("E")
            .Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4  ="""","""",VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,'Master Control'!A:R,18,0))"
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        End With
        With .Columns("F")
            .Columns("F").Formula = "=IF('CT Accounts'!A4="""","""",VLOOKUP('CT Accounts'!A4,Inactive!A:T,20,0))"
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        End With
        
        'etc etc
    End With
End Sub
```